# Google Charts: Adding stroke to points

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I wish to add a stroke around the points in my Google line chart.

From the [points-documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points) of Google Charts (bottom) we have that:

> The following style customizations are available: [...] 
>   - stroke-color (Specified as a hex string.)
>   - stroke-width (Specified as a hex string.)

I can't find the documentation of how to add these options. Anyone, who can figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from one of google's examples ( see https://jsfiddle.net/j9sgdr4d/)

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
        ([['X', 'Y', {'type': 'string', 'role': 'style'}],
          [1, 3, null],
          [2, 2.5, null],
          [3, 3, null],
          [4, 4, null],
          [5, 4, 'point { size: 18; shape-type: star; fill-color: #a52714'],
          [6, 3, 'point { size: 18; shape-type: star; fill-color: #a52714; stroke-color: #ff0000; stroke-width: 5'],
          [7, 2.5, null],
          [8, 3, null]
    ]);
```

[image]